# Trigger button click in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Say I have a Panel with many Button and PictureBox controls. Each control has an associated Click event. This is a touchscreen application, so the user may be a little imprecise with their click (or the touchscreen calibration might not be perfect). So, I'd like to handle the click event on the panel and then programmatically call the Button's or PictureBox's Click event if the click is close to a button/picture.

A number of other answers suggest using the "PerformClick" event, but this is not supported in the Compact Framework. Any alternatives? My code:

```
private void pnlButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point ptClick = Control.MousePosition;
    foreach (Control cntrl in pnlButtons.Controls)
    {
        // Make sure the control is visible!
        if (cntrl.Visible)
        {
            // Click close to control?
            if ((ptClick.X > (cntrl.Left - 5)) &&
                (ptClick.X < (cntrl.Right + 5)) &&
                (ptClick.Y > (cntrl.Top - 5)) &&
                (ptClick.Y < (cntrl.Bottom + 5)))
            {
                // Click Button or PictureBox without cntrl.PerformClick?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to perform the click event rather than the function called by the click event? So: Click event CE1 calls function A which calls function B, C, D and E. Instead of calling CE1 you could just call A.

Comment: Yes, good thought, but each control on the panel does a slightly different function. So button A => A_click which calls FunctionA(), button B => B_click which calls FunctionB(), PictureBox C => C_click which calls FunctionC(), etc for lots of buttons and pictures.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have the time or things in place to write out the answer in full, but I believe this isn't that difficult. First off, try subclassing button and calling the click event from your own PerformClick. Else, You can write a method which takes a button and performs a click. First get the handle of the control, then p/invoke the windows API functions to send a mousedown then mouseup event to it. I believe it is the SendMessage function. All you have to do then is write the logic to find the closest button and pass it to the function. Or, write it as an extension method to Button...

Comment: @Alan: Good idea, thanks. I've just P/Invoked SendMessage and sent a WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP message to the control and it works as expected. If you knock up a quick answer, I can accept that. Otherwise, I'll answer along those lines tomorrow.

Comment: @AlainD You're welcome, posted as answer, feel free to edit it and copy pasta the DllImports for future users' sake.

Comment: @Alan: OK, edited answer with full code (subject to review) and accepted answer. Ciao!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, try subclassing button and calling the click event from your own PerformClick. Else, You can write a method which takes a button and performs a click. First get the handle of the control, then p/invoke the windows API functions to send a mousedown then mouseup event to it. I believe it is the SendMessage function. All you have to do then is write the logic to find the closest button and pass it to the function. Or, write it as an extension method to Button

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

EDIT:
Here's the full code to simulate a click by sending a mousedown and mouseup message to the control:

```
// Windows constants for mouse messages
private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN        = 0x0201;
private const int WM_LBUTTONUP          = 0x0202;

// P/Invoke for SendMessage
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int nMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

// Method to click a control
public void ClickControl(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    // Send a MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP message to the control to simulate a click
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}

// Method to handle click event on parent Panel control
private void pnlButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // See if the click point is close to a (visible) button and if so, click the button.
    // The user was probably a little imprecise or the screen might need re-calibration.
    Point pt = pnlButtons.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

    // Now look for any Button / PictureBox controls nearby
    foreach (Control cntrl in pnlButtons.Controls)
    {
        Rectangle inflated = cntrl.Bounds;
        inflated.Inflate(4, 5);
        if (cntrl.Visible && inflated.Contains(pt))
        {
            // Simulate a click on the control
            ClickControl(cntrl.Handle);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlainD looks good. I helped simplify the code a little more.

Comment: @AlainD I removed the one LINQ expression, should be fine even in older versions of CF

Comment: @AlainD Np, I corrected it, sorry I didn't fire up a IDE and new project just to write out the example.. I mean it doesn't matter too much it was "close enough" for anyone to get it right. It didn't use completely new .NET 4.5 or 5.0 features.. =)

Comment: OK, edit approved, this combines your code improvements and compiles in the CF! Other comments deleted (you may want to delete yours as well). Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Since you can't use `PerformClick`, you won't be able to rely on the control's `Click` event handler firing automatically in this case.  Instead, just make a method that takes a control and figure out from that control which action to take.  Example:

```
private void pnlButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point ptClick = Control.MousePosition;
    foreach (Control cntrl in pnlButtons.Controls)
    {
        // Make sure the control is visible!
        if (cntrl.Visible)
        {
            // Click close to control?
            if ((ptClick.X > (cntrl.Left - 5)) &&
                (ptClick.X < (cntrl.Right + 5)) &&
                (ptClick.Y > (cntrl.Top - 5)) &&
                (ptClick.Y < (cntrl.Bottom + 5)))
            {
                handleClick (cntrl);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void handleClick(Control c)
{
    if (c == button1)
    {
        // handle button1 click, e.g. by calling its `Click` handler
    }
    else if (c == picureBox1)
    {
        // handle pictureBox1 click
    }
    // et cetera
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put all the stuff from your button click handler to a separate function, and call that function instead of triggering a button click.

```
private void pnlButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point ptClick = Control.MousePosition;
    foreach (Control cntrl in pnlButtons.Controls)
    {
        // Make sure the control is visible!
        if (cntrl.Visible)
        {
            // Click close to control?
            if ((ptClick.X > (cntrl.Left - 5)) &&
                (ptClick.X < (cntrl.Right + 5)) &&
                (ptClick.Y > (cntrl.Top - 5)) &&
                (ptClick.Y < (cntrl.Bottom + 5)))
            {
                PerformActionsOnClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PerformActionsOnClick();
}
void PerformActionsOnClick()
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```